# Convert decimal to binary, octa and hexadecimal using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, stack

I try to convert decimal to binary, octa and hexadecimal, i need the output to be like this **using recursion and without built-in**

```
Decimal: 10
Decimal to Binary: 01010
Decimal to Octa: 12
Decimal to Hexa: A
```

So far i just got this solving way without recursion

```
decimal = int(input("Input decimal:"))
#convert binary
def bin(decimal):
    if decimal >= 1:
        bi(decimal // 2)
    return decimal % 2
#convert octa
def octa(decimal):
    if decimal >= 1:
        octa(decimal // 8)
    return decimal % 8
def hex(decimal):
    if decimal >= 1:
        hex(decimal // 16)
    return decimal % 16
```

Is there a way to make it more simple just using one `def` with recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with a single recursive function as follows:

- base as a function argument
- default digits as an argument to cover the different digits for the various bases

**Code**

```
def convert(n, base, digits = "0123456789ABCDEF"):
    ' Function to convert decimal number binary another base '
    if n >= base:
       return convert(n//base, base) + digits[n%base]
    else:
        return digits[n]
```

**Test**

```
n = 10                    # Decimal number
for base in [2, 8, 16]:   # Bases
    print(f'Decimal {n} to base {base} = {convert(n, base)}')
```

**Output**

```
Decimal 10 to base 2 = 1010
Decimal 10 to base 8 = 12
Decimal 10 to base 16 = A
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by taking the number and the base as the input
As we know that the base value is 2 for binary, 8 for octal, 16 for hexadecimal
Try the following code

```
import math
def func(num, base):
    count=0
    while int(num/math.pow(base,(count+1))) > 0:
        count=count+1
    new = []
    while num >= 0:
        p = math.pow(base,count)
        if p == 1:
            new.append(num)
            break
        new.append(int(num / p))
        num = num- new[-1]*p
        count=count-1
    s=""
    for i in new:
        s=s+str(int(i))
    return s
num=int(input())
base=int(input())
print(func(num,base))
```